# Is it possible to use all while loop inside an array?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, while-loop

We can use `for` loop inside an array,
for example: `arr = [i for i in range(10)]`

I want to add all the digits of an number into array; can we use the same methodology and implement using `while` loop?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown is a *list comprehension*, not a loop inside an array.

There is no such thing that involves the `while` keyword.

---

It's possible to define a *generator* with a `while` loop and then use that generator in a list comprehension.

For example, this generates all digits of a non-negative integer (in reverse order):

```
def digits(n):
    while True:
        n, d = divmod(n, 10)
        yield d
        if n == 0:
            break

arr = [i for i in digits(123)]  # [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to add all the digits of an number into array can we sue the same methodology and implement using while loop?

No, you cannot do a similar thing with a while loop. The syntax `[i for i in range(10)]` is called a "list comprehension". If you google these words, you will find more information about how they work.

For the digits of a number, I suggest turning it into a string:

```
number = 12345
digits = str(number)
```

Now you can use `digits` like an array of digit characters:

```
print(digits[2]) # output: 3
for d in digits:
    print(d)
```

If you want a list of digits as integers rather than characters:

```
digits = [int(c) for c in str(number)]
```